# How to compare popularity of MediaWiki (eg. Wikipedia) pages?

Tags: mediawiki

Given two or more MediaWiki pages (eg. Wikipedia), what is a meaningful and publicly accessible measure of their relative popularity?

Comment: MediaWiki can show **page view count** at the bottom of every page. Specifically on Wikipedia that feature is turned off though.

Answer (score 2):

On http://stats.grok.se/ there are statistics available for most Wikipediae. Just enter the article name and you can see the views in the chosen month.

Comment: How can I obtain a list of articles, sorted from most popular to least popular?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Well there is raw data available: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/ You can download and sort it yourself.